# Which php design pattern is more powerfull?

Tags: php

I want to know that from all the 5 common pattern for the php (The factory pattern, The singleton pattern,The observer pattern,The chain-of-command pattern,The strategy pattern) which one is more recommended , powerful and easy to use as well ?

Comment: what does it mean, "Powerful"?

Comment: It looks like that you are searching for some kind of final solution. There is no such thing. Every design pattern has its purpose and is useful when certain conditions are met.

Comment: I never knew PHP had *only* 5 design patterns!

Comment: Which is more powerful: a bicycle or a fish? The patterns you mention are tools for different purposes so I don't see them as comparable.

Comment: The question is completely meaningless. Design patterns don't compete on power, ease of use, recommendability, etc. They are all *different*. And there are *no* design patterns 'for' PHP. Design patterns belong to everybody, or at least to all the possible languages they can be implemented in.

Answer (score 4):

The one that best fits the problem at hand. Design patterns are tools, not a way of life.

Comment: To add to this: The design patterns named in the question are all part of a programmer's toolbox. They aren't alternatives, or competitors, to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read anything about them? They are solving completely different problems - is like you would compare apples with grapes - which one of them better?

Answer (score 0):

Each pattern is as powerfull as the programer who is building the application at hand. Unskilled programers tend to use the patterns is an incorrect way, or not the actual mentioned way a pattern should be used.

Each pattern is equally "strong" or usefull if used and applied in the right situation and right coding enviorment.

Learn all 5 of them, read about them and ask of search for specific usages for them .